# Activity get Intent from different activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

First Activity (Home) Input name then send to Second Activity(Menu) and put it to textview
Second Activity get intent from Third Activity(Event) when list item clicked and put it to button name.

how to get intent from third activity that haven't send it to second activity ???

```
Home.class

Intent intent = new Intent(Home.this, Menu.class);
intent.putExtra("username", username.getText().toString()); 
StartActivity(intent);
finish(); //success

Menu.class

Intent intent = this.getIntent();
textName.setText(intent.getExtras().getString("username"));
buttonEvent.setText(intent.getExtras().getString("event")); // error null

Event.class
EventModel eventModel = (EventModel)aEventModel.get(mPosition);
Intent intent = new Intent(Event.this, Menu.class);
intent.putExtra("username", eventModel.getName()); 
StartActivity(intent);
finish(); //success
```

Comment: try intent.getStringExtra('username') instead.

Comment: it's still get null ..

Comment: How will you get the intent value when the third activity is no initiated yet. You need to first make the third activity visible so that it can load the values. But to me, it doesn't sound very clear on what you are trying to achieve. Can you define your application flow and how your app will work ?

Comment: i mean second activity also get data from third activity after it's sending data. But if i initiated a intent data from 3 activity. Data is null . How do i know if 3 activity has send a data to 2 activity ?

Comment: `Data is null`. I see no variable with the name `Data` or `data` in your code. Please be to the point.

Answer (score 0):

in your third activity (Event class) you are binding the data with tag: "**username**" not with "**event**",

```
intent.putExtra("username", eventModel.getName());
```

then how can you get the same with tag : **event**, the line should contain:

```
intent.putExtra("event", eventModel.getName());
```